# Backbone.js: apply active classes to active element in template?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone template that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="template-switchers">
<strong><%= activeViz %></strong>
<button class="btn" data-viz="lists"><i class="icon-list icon-large"></i></button>
<button class="btn" data-viz="atomic"><i class="icon-spinner icon-large"></i></button>
<button class="btn" data-viz="maps"><i class="icon-map-marker icon-large"></i></button>
<button class="btn" data-viz="charts"><i class="icon-bar-chart icon-large"></i></button>
</script>
```

The `activeViz` parameter passed in can be any of `lists`, `atomic`, `maps` and `charts`. My question is: how do I add an `active` class to the appropriate button?

To date, I've been doing this with jQuery:

```
$('#viz-switchers button[data-viz="'+ activeViz + '"]').addClass('active');
```

But now I want to refactor for Backbone, and use templates. Is there a better, Backboney way, without having four `if` statements in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create array of buttons and render it in loop e.g:

```
var buttons = [{viz:'', icon:''}, {}, {}];
```

And In your template render buttons:

```
<% _.each(buttons, function(button) { %>
    <button class="btn" data-viz="<%= button.viz %>">
        <i class="<%= button.icon %> icon-large <% button.viz === activeViz && print('active') %>"></i>
    </button>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: IMO this is the right idea, in that you're describing the model that will be fed into the template. My only suggestion here would be to keep the loop (_.each) in the render method, and keep the template simply as the markup. Better separation of concerns and easier to maintain. /2c